# replace NA in same group with value

Tags: r

```
DF<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3),code=c("A","NA","A","NA","E"))
> DF
  id code
1  1    A
2  1   NA
3  2    A
4  3   NA
5  3    E
```

Desired output:

```
  id code
1  1    A
2  1    A
3  2    A
4  3    E
5  3    E
```

I want to replace NA in each group with non-NA value.

Best H

Comment: What if there are none or multiple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(code = first(code[!is.na(cod)]))
```

---

Or could also be `fill` if the intention is to replace the NA with the previous non-NA

```
library(tidyr)
DF %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   fill(code)
```